# DDD - Relaxing the rule of Eventual Consistency between aggregate

Tags: domain-driven-design, eventual-consistency

I`m reading the book PATTERNS, PRINCIPLES, AND PRACTICES OF DOMAIN-DRIVEN DESIGN, written by Scott Millett with Nike Tune. In the chapter 19, Aggregates, he states:

> Sometimes it is actually good practice to modify multiple aggregates within a transaction. But it’s
>   important to understand why the guidelines exist in the first place so that you can be aware of the
>   consequences of ignoring them.
>
> When the cost of eventual consistency is too high, it’s acceptable to consider modifying two objects in the same transaction. Exceptional circumstances will usually be when the business tells you that the customer experience will be too unsatisfactory.
>
> To summarize, saving one aggregate per transaction is the default approach. But you should
>   collaborate with the business, assess the technical complexity of each use case, and consciously ignore
>   the guideline if there is a worthwhile advantage, such as a better user experience.

I face to a case in my project when user request a operation to my app and this operation affects two aggregate, and there are rules that must be verified by the two aggregates for the operation takes place successfully.
it is something like "Allocating a cell for a detainee":

1. the user makes the request
2. the Detainee (AR1) is fetched from database and receives a command: detainee.AllocateTo(cellId);
   3  the Cell (AR2) is fetched and receive a command: cell.Allocate(detaineeId);

Both steps 2 and 3 could throw an exception, depending on the detainee's status and cell capacity. But abstract it.

Using eventual consistency, if step 2 is executed successfully, emiting the event DetaineeAllocated, but step 3 fails (will run in another transaction, inside an event handler), the state of aggregates will be inconsistent, and worse, the operation seemed to be executed successfully for the user.

I know that there are cases like "when the user makes a purchase over $ 100, its type must be changed to VIP" that can be implemented using eventual consistency, but the case I mentioned does not seem to be one.

Do you think that this is a special case that the book mentions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each aggregate must not have an invalid state (internal state), but that does not imply aggregates have to be consistent with one another (external, or system state).

Given the context of your question, the answer could be either yes or no.

### The Case for No

The external state can become eventually consistent, which may be acceptable to your product owner. In this case you design ways to detect the inconsistency and deal with it (e.g. by retrying operations, issuing compensating transactions, etc.)

### The Case for Yes

In your orchestration layer, go ahead and update the aggregates in a transaction. You might choose to do this because it's "easy" and "right", or you might choose to do this because your product owner says the inconsistency can't be tolerated for whatever reason.

### Another Case for No

There's another way out for saying this is not a special case, not a reason for more than one transaction. That way out requires a change to your model. Consider removing the mutual dependency between your detainee and the cell, and instead introducing another aggregate, `CellAssignment`, which represents a [moment-interval](http://curtis.schlak.com/2013/05/08/modeling-in-color-part-iii.html) (a temporal relationship) that can be constructed and saved in a single transaction. In this case, your detainee and the cell don't change.

Comment: My PO says that the user experience seems to be bad if a fail occurs between the commands. So, in this case, i will choose yes. Thanks.

Comment: Beside that, create a CellAssignment, affects the Cell aggregate, its avaliable capacity should be decreased, and should be checked before create CellAssignment

Answer (score 1):

"the state of aggregates will be inconsistent"

Well, it shouldn't be inconsistent forever or that wouldn't be **eventual** consistency. You would normally discuss with business experts to establish an acceptable consistency timeframe.

Should something go wrong an event will be raised which should trigger compensating actions and perhaps a notification to a human stating something went wrong after-all.

Another approach could be to introduce a process manager which is responsible to carry out the business process by triggering commands and listening to events, until completion or timeout. The ARs are often designed to allow small incremental steps 
towards consistency. For instance, there could be a command to reserve cell space first rather than directly allocating the detainee. The UI could always poll the state of the process to know when it's complete if necessary.

Eventual consistency obviously comes at a cost. If you have a single DB in a monolith that doesn't need extreme scalability you could very well favor to modify both ARs in a single transaction until that becomes a problem.
 Eventual consistency is often sold as less costly that strong consistency, but I believe that's mostly for distributed systems where you'd have to deal with XA transactions.

Answer (score 0):

> Do you think that this is a special case that the book mentions?

No.

What I suspect you have here is a modeling error.

From your description, it sounds like you are dealing with something like a `CellAssignment`, and the invariant that you are trying to maintain is to ensure that there are no conflicts among active cell assignments.

That suggests to me that you are missing some sort of aggregate - something like a seating chart? - that keeps track of all of the active assignments and conflicts.

How can you know?  One way is to graph your aggregates; create a node for each piece of information you need to save, and join nodes with lines if there is a rule that requires locking both nodes.  If you find yourself with disconnected graphs, or two graphs that only connect at the root id, then it's a good bet that separating some information into a new graph will improve your modeling.

[All Our Aggregates Are Wrong](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KkzvQSuYd5I), by Mauro Servienti, would be a good talk to review.

Comment: Wouldn't have a single AR for the whole set of cells increase contention much more than just modifying 2 ARs?

Comment: "It depends"; if you discover that CellAssignment really is a separate aggregate (backed by its own tables!), you can then tune that part of the data store independently from everything else, and choose the lock design that best fits your traffic.

Comment: Previous remark should be interpreted as conjecture; I don't have nearly enough personal laps at this end of the spectrum to be making strong unsupported claims.